# Gitlab CI: Use `rules` to check if value exists in an array

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci

I am using an anchor for defining list of branches to run some stages of my pipeline on like so:

```
.branches:
  &BRANCHES:
  - master
  - my-feature-branch
```

I want to use the `rules` in a way that it checks if the commit branch is same as one of the branches listed in the `BRANCHES` variable, and if true then do something:

```
rules:
 - if: ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH in *BRANCHES)
   // Do something
```

I know this syntax is wrong, so how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Since [YAML anchors](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#anchors) are used for variable assignations or scripts, a simpler approach (described in [this thread](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/array-variable-in-gitlab-ci-cd-yml/46201/2?u=vonc)) would be to use an actual string array, in a shell-based `script:` section:

```
BRANCHES="master my-feature-branch"
for BRANCH in ${BRANCHES}
do
  if [[ "${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}" == "${BRANCH}" ]]; then
    # do something
  fi
done
```

Comment: how would you put that into a "rules: - if: "

Comment: @Kappacake You would not. The job would run the script part, which would "do something" only if its inner condition is true.

Comment: The "problem" with it is that you cannot prevent a job from triggering with that, and the pipeline will always show that job as executed successfully and the user would have to check the job's log and see if it actually run or not.
Is there not a clean way to only run a job if the current branch is within a list of branches?

Comment: I am trying to do what's described on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74716764/gitlab-ci-check-if-branch-is-within-list-of-branches/74717203#74717203

Comment: @Kappacake Yes, with that approach, the job always runs, and can set up a variable that another job can use to decide if it needs to run or not.