# GitLab CI - Check if branch is within list of branches

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to be able to set a list of branches on the GitLab CICD variables on the UI and have the pipeline check that list to see if it should run a specific job.

I am trying to turn this rule:

```
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "poc5"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "poc5-s1"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "poc5-s2"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "poc5-s3"
```

Into this:

```
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH in $DEFAULT_BRANCHES
```

Where `$DEFAULT_BRANCHES` is a variable defined in the projects CICD variables as follows:

`DEFAULT_BRANCHES:`

```
poc5
poc5-s1
poc5-s2
poc5-s3
```

or

```
poc5 poc5-s1 poc5-s2 poc5-s3
```

The best I could come up with was the following, which results in an invalid syntax for GitLab CI rules:

```
  rules:
    - if: echo $DEFAULT_BRANCHES | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -q -E "^${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}$"
```

I am essentially trying to not have the list of branches hard coded into the pipeline yml file.

Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

A solution is:

```yaml
# .gitlab-ci.yml

if: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'poc5' || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'poc5-s1' || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'poc5-s2' || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'poc5-s3'"
      when: on_success
```

But a shorter version with regex is:

```yaml
# .gitlab-ci

if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^poc5(-s[1-3])?$/
    when: on_success
```

Comment: That was the original syntax I had and I am trying to change. The point of what I'm trying above is to be able to set the default branches from the GitLab UI without changing the .yml file